# What is preferable way to upgrade system?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

There are (at minimum) two ways to upgrade Ubuntu.

- Using Update Manager.
- Using `apt-get upgrade` (`sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade`) in a terminal.

Are those two ways equal or is one of them preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equal. `apt-get upgrade` doesn't upgrade releases at all, it just upgrades packages in the current release sources.

The Update Manager is the GUI frontend to `apt-get`, and the command line equivalent for that would be `do-release-upgrade` (without `sudo`). These two would be more or less  equivalent.

If `do-release-upgrade` reports `No new release found`, check that in Software & Update, the setting "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" is set to "any version".

Answer (score 1):

We have a common mis-understanding of what 'upgrade' and 'dist-upgrade' mean for apt-get.

In summary: **neither one upgrades Ubuntu (or Debian) releases**. But they **are** different. Usually, the best option is to use dist-upgrade. Unless there is a technical reason, **always** do a dist-upgrade.

From the man [page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html):

upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
           **currently installed** on the system from the sources enumerated in
           /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new
           versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
           circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
           not already installed retrieved and installed. *New versions of
           currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
           changing the install status of another package will be left at
           their current version*. An update must be performed first so that
           apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.

dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
           *also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
           of packages*; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
           it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
           expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade
           command may therefore remove some packages. The
           /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations from which
           to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for
           a mechanism for overriding the general settings for individual
           packages.

Answer (score 0):

They are equal, but you may find the terminal method more convenient since you don't have to navigate through GUIs.